# Umbraco repeating content area

Tags: umbraco

I want to make a repeater field in umbraco width tinymce with it, but when i try to use embedded content package all i get is a normal textarea, and when i use the tinyMCE which is at the top of the tab the cursor jumps to the main content area.
What am i doing wrong?
Is there another package to do this or is it possible to make a datatype which can repeat?

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a datatype which repeats a richtext-field multiple times in the Umbraco client?
You can create custom datatypes in Umbraco, if that is what you need...

Comment: I want to accomplish that my client can add a new group of content etc "title, content, link, image" which gets outputted in seperated boxes but the output i think i can accomplish it's how i make the group of fields on the backend. as i said i tried "embedded content" which worked fine but when it came to use the wysiwyg editor it jumps to the main content area.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I have a "block" of content like you describe in your comment above I create content as data to help with that.

Steps:

- Create new DocTypes called "Block" and a "Block Folder".  Allow
  "Block" under "Block Folder"
- Add properties to "Block" for the content, link, and image (title is
  the node name)
- Create the folder and sample blocks in the content
  tree.  Generally outside of the Home tree, but it certainly can be
  under Home.
- Create a Multi-node Tree Picker data type that selects the content in the "Block Folder" in the content tree
- Add a new property to the page that you want the "blocks" to be selected on and select them in the content

Does that make sense?  Overkill for your project?  I've found it to be a nice pattern in general.